# /u/0 in google plus urls

Tags: google-plus

Why do google plus urls have `plus.google.com/u/0` as base url even though all urls work fine without `/u/0` at the end. Is there any special purpose behind such a design ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's used by a new feature Google introduced recently, Multiple Sign-in Account, the 0 means default account, 1 would be second account and so on.

Is not exclusive of Google+, you can see it in all the product

Comment: Cool. I've always used multiple browser profiles in chrome to swap between work and personal. How is this intended to be used? Bookmarking?